# Spring Boot 2 AuthoritiesExtractor

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I encountered a problem when I tried to migrate from Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.0.0.RELEASE.

I have implemented the AuthoritiesExtractor interface and it's working in version 1.5.10, but in version 2.0.0 I got this error

`class AuthoritiesExtractor not found in path org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource`

It really can't be found.

Comment: Spring Boot 2 Javadoc shows that AuthoritiesExtractor is just there on the right package https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/AuthoritiesExtractor.html
Did you check whether you have it in your classpath?

Comment: It's M4 , but M5 and above include RELEASE this interface dose not exist.

Comment: There seems to be an open issue with Spring Security that could be behind this cf. https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/30
It's unclear what the status is on this.

Answer (score 2):

The `AuthoritiesExtractor` interface has been moved from the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` dependency to the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For versions >=2.0.0m5 (2.0.1.RELEASE - 2.1.3.RELEASE)
Import it via:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.AuthoritiesExtractor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure how this solved it, because AuthoritiesExtractor doesn't exist after 2.0.0m5.